# Unable to access header files in unreal engine 4.25 using visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unreal-engine4

Hello all and thank you for checking out my question,

I am following a tutorial learning unreal engine with UE 4.25 with c++. I am currently stuck on the static mesh portion of the code. For some reason, it seems like I am unable to access the header files needed, not only for Components but for any of the major folders like Engine.

When I type in the #include " " only loose header files pop up and none are the ones I need(pictures won't post so ill post the relevant code).

This is from the .h file:

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Bullet.generated.h"

```
UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT_API ABullet : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    ABullet();
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    class UStaticMeshComponent* BulletMesh;
}
```

This is from the .cpp

```
#include "Bullet.h"
//Components/StaticMeshComponent.h should go here but it doesn't show with the      #include for some reason
// Sets default values
ABullet::ABullet()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to
    // improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    
    BulletMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>("BulletMesh");
    
}
```

Comment: Is this an intellisense issue or does it also fail to find the include files when you compile?

Comment: It doesn't have an issue with the autogenerated ones at all like "CoreMinimal.h", and "GameFramework/Actor.h"

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an intellisense issue in Visual Studio. It takes vanilla Visual Studio a long time to parse UE, and I personally have just turned it off and use [Visual Assist X](https://www.wholetomato.com/) instead.

You can just do `#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"` and it should compile fine. [Classifier](http://classifier.celdevs.com/) is a great free resource for helping you find the include paths you need, and is really helpful for getting started with Unreal.

Another option would be to try out [Rider for Unreal](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/rider-unreal/) instead of Visual Studio, which has much better intellisense/code helpers for UE based on what I have seen.

Comment: I thought it would be too but when I compile the code it doesn't have issues with the other headers from unreal engine such as "CoreMinimal.h". I will definitely give the Rider for Unreal a try though! thanks